# Navigation won't vertically align

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to vertically align on my navigation menu. I tried `display:table-cell;  vertical-align: middle;`, but it just won't. 
I do not want to apply `padding-top or margin top`. 
How do I manage to do this?

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/27kquzm3/

Comment: remove float:left; in selector #cssmenu > ul > li

Comment: remove your `margin: 0; ` to your `#cssmenu ul`

Comment: Try using line-height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give `display:table` to the `ul` and remove `float:left;` and then give `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;` to the `li` element.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#cssmenu ul
{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/27kquzm3/1/)

Comment: @Kami Is that all you want? I also fixed the top border. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/27kquzm3/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This work out perfectly. But for some reason, when I added the code as you provided my color on navigation bar automatically removed when I resize the screen, and also it gives me vertically scroll. Just a moment please I will provide you with jsfiddle.

Comment: Only home navmenu is coloured with black color. The rest color has disappear for some reason. I am sorry. I have added media query code there to show u my mobile navbar version. What it happens. here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/27kquzm3/1/

Comment: In jsfiddle, it looks okay. For scrolling problem, you should have a different menu in small screen. There are a lot of plugins which do that. I think [this  link](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/5-free-responsive-menus-navigations-for-mobile) can help you.

Comment: Ah, sorry I shared the wrong link. Here is the link where you see that home navmenu is coloured with black color, but other navmenu is not. https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/27kquzm3/5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94520/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-kami).

Answer (score 3):

```
#cssmenu{
width:100%;
padding-top:13px;
}
```

Try it out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do want to avoid adding padding-top or margin top.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 3200px;
  top:0%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  background-color: rgba(14, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#cssmenu ul{
width:90%;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    display: table;
height: 100%;
}

#cssmenu li{


}

#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width:500px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;

}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
   display:table-cell;
height: 90px;
vertical-align: middle;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  border-top: 4px solid #cd4650;
  color: #cd4650;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;

}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

/*submenu*/
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: rgba(29, 15, 6, 0.7);
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  margin-top: 15px;
  
 
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/*submenu*/
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {

  color: #cd4650;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a class="first" href="#f">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="introduction" href="#introduction">Intro</a></li>
<li><a class="background" href="#background">Background <br>Placement </a></li>
<li><a class="ira" href="#ira">illatruation & ira</a></li>
<li><a class="corporate" href="#cusrporate">Corporate<br>View</a></li>


            

</ul>
</div>
```